# Chkdisk on a pre-boot authentication truecrypt drive via VirtualBox

Tags: windows, linux, virtualbox, truecrypt, repair

2 drives:

150gb - Linux Mint (not encrypted)

300gb - Windows Vista 64-bit (truecrypt with preboot authentication)

I need to repair my windows install (freezes trying to load a system dll, spinrite gives the drive a clean bill of health, so its just a corrupted system file.) Running repair off the windows install dvd wont work because it can't see my windows partition (due to truecrypt).

### Here's what i've done:

- Boot into linux partition, install virtualbox and truecrypt gui
- Use truecrypt GUI to mount the windows drive (it is now mounted under `/media/truecrypt1`, and I can see all of my files, great! I can at least save the redownload time of installing my steam games if I have to reinstall)
- I created a virtualmachine and attached the host DVD drive to it so it can boot the windows installation dvd.

I want to be able to have the virtualmachine repair the windows install that is currently mounted under `/media/truecrypt1`. How do I create a passthrough vmdk so that I can mount it in the virtualmachine so that the windows repair tool will be able to see the windows install.

### SOLUTION (thanks to tapped-out):

- create vmdk passthrough so that virtualbox can use the truecrypt drive: `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename ./passthrough.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/mapper/truecrypt1`
- Run virtualbox as root: `sudo virtualbox`
- Add the `passthrough.vmdk` to your virtualmachine's drives
- Boot the virtualmachine from the windows install dvd, click `Repair computer`
- It will NOT find the drive to repair, but if you click `Load Drivers` it will allow you to browse your windows install. Don't load any drivers, just click `Next`. There will be an option to allow you to open a command prompt.
- `cd /D c:\` and then `chkdsk /f /r`

Dont know if it will fix my corrupt dll, but mission accomplished: mounted a pre-boot authenticated truecrypt drive under a virtualmachine so I could run checkdisk on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a terminal, you will want to run this command:

`VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename ./passthrough.vmdk -rawdisk /media/truecrypt1 -register`

You can then mount this in a VM as normal.

**EDIT:** the register parameter has apparently been deprecated, and you need to use the block device, not the mounted partition:

`VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename ./passthrough.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/mapper/truecrypt1`

Comment: invalid parameter `-register`

Comment: sudo VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename ./passthrough.vmdk -rawdisk /media/truecrypt1

VBoxManage: error: File '/media/truecrypt1' is no block device
VBoxManage: error: The raw disk vmdk file was not created

Comment: oh, I see. /media/truecrypt1 isn't a blockdevice, it's the partition. what happens if you run `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename ./passthrough.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/mapper/truecrypt1`?

Comment: That works! at least it created the vmdk, but now I get this error when trying to use it `Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
Medium
Interface: 
IMedium {53f9cc0c-e0fd-40a5-a404-a7a5272082cd} Callee: 
IVirtualBox {c28be65f-1a8f-43b4-81f1-eb60cb516e66}`

Comment: seems like a common problem on linux, according to [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1198060). what happens if you run `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`?

Comment: AH soo close. I don't have `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv` but I found somewhere else where someone said to just run virtualbox as root. That works! at least I can add the drive to my virtual machine, but windows repair tool doesn't show the drive in the list of windows installs that I can repair. UGH. To throw salt in the wound, it will let me browse the drive for disk drivers (it even recognizes it as C:\) it just won't let me repair it.

Comment: Got it to run chkdsk, mission accomplished, i don't know if it will fix my corrupt dll, but i got it to work. I'll edit the above question to put the solution in there, thanks!